# How to animate the Counter value in UI to increase the value in C# WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, wpf-animation

I want to develop an application in WPF, and same in Windows Phone 8.1. Where I want to increase the value of a variable from 100 to 200, from 200 to 300 and go on. This is a score of the game. Now I want to animate this in the UI. I have written a sample code like this.

```
<Button Click="Button_Click" >Start</Button>
<TextBlock x:Name="tbvalue" />
```

So when the button is clicked the value will be from 100 to 200, but this should be displayed in the UI like 101,102,103 ... with incremental value animated in the UI.

I have written the code behind like

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    while (count < upperLimit)
    {
        count += 1;
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action<object>(perform), sender);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    }

    i++;
    upperLimit = i * 100;
}
```

and in that

```
private void perform(object obj)
{
    tbvalue.Text = count.ToString();
}
```

But using this I am not achieving the counter animation. any ideas or suggestions how to achieve this functionality.

Comment: You can use dispatcherTimer and its start and stop events to do this

Answer (score 4):

This is what I did and it is working fine.I made a **demo wpf application**

```
 public MainWindow()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
            Counter_Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
            Counter_Timer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
            counter.Content = 100;
        }
        private readonly DispatcherTimer Counter_Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Counter_Timer.Start();
        }

        public void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            counter.Content = Convert.ToInt16(counter.Content) + 1;
        if (Convert.ToInt16(counter.Content) >= 200)
        {
            Counter_Timer.Stop();
        }
        }
```

Xaml File:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Grid.Row="0" Name="Counter" ></Button>
        <Label Name="counter" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Whats with the negative??

Comment: Its not working, its incrementing the value but 100, 200, 300 not incrementing like I mentioned in my question, However FYI, I didn't mark this as negative vote.

Comment: Oh yes, its working, but very slow, How to make it a faster? If I do Counter_Timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1, 1, 1000); Its not working, dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e) is not hitting at all

Comment: Faster? It will work in the same manner as seconds changes. the way seconds increases 101 102 103...

Comment: Ok I got it it can be done using Counter_Timer.Interval =  TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10); This is what i was looking for. Thanks

Comment: I didn't ask anything different, after seeing the progress the counter is doing I noticed its very slow, So I thought milliseconds will do the job. Anyways thanks for the help. I owe you!

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel approach (this will animate text change from 0 to 100 when button clicked)

```
public MainWindowViewModel()
{
   BtnClicked = new DelegateCommand(() => TextBlockValue += 100);
}

private double value;
public double TextBlockValue
{
    set
    {
        DispatcherTimer counterTimer = new DispatcherTimer
        {
            Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5),
        };
        counterTimer.Tick += (sender, args) =>
        {
            SetProperty(ref this.value, this.value + 1);
            if (this.value >= value) counterTimer.Stop();
        };
        counterTimer.Start();
    }
    get => value;
}
```